# CodeIgniter - Load a view part with another language than the current language

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm currently trying to prepare a view part into a variable but I must load the view part in a different language of the application.

I have my languages folder sets (french & english) and here what I tried with no success :

```
// Current language is french
$this->lang->load('[lang_file]', 'english');
$variable = $this->load->view('[path_to_view]', true);
$this->lang->load('[lang_file]');
```

First, is it possible to load another view in another language than the one currently in place ?

Second, if yes, what do I need to do ?

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe temporary setting the language to english before loading the view file does the trick. Try this one:

```
$this->config->set_item('language', 'english');
$variable = $this->load->view('[path_to_view]', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you should use `$this->lang->load()`, but maybe yours works aswell.

Bascily, yes it works. The lang keys will be overwritten, and new ones applied.

Do you have `french` as default language in your `config/config.php`?

And more importantly, is your view fetching data which the view uses before you run `$this->load->language('[lang_file]', 'english');`? There might be some passed errors from `form_validation` and simliar which will get the "wrong" language.

Comment: I just corrected my sample code. Yes, french is my default language in my app. My code is executed after the $this->form_validation->run() method.

Comment: Then the errors will be in french while the rest of the view is in english. Consider putting the `lang->load()` before `->run()`. But what result are you getting?

Comment: I cannot put my `lang->load()` before the `->run()` because the language the view part need is into `$this->input->post()`